# finding username during GCP startup script

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am launching a GCP instance using their python API where I am installing docker and other packages through the startup script. The issue is that the startup script runs as root and subsequently I can only run `docker` as root. Ideally, I would like to add the user into the docker group, so it can run docker without invoking `sudo`.

the thing is I do not remember specifying any user name when creating the instance and depending on how I `ssh` into the instance (whether I let GCP manage ssh keys  or use my uploaded key), I get different user names.

So, I am wondering if there is a way to find out what users can connect to this instance and add them to the docker user group in the startup script?

Comment: Are you using the os-login capabilitiy of compute engine or ssh keys?

Comment: @kolban At the moment ssh-keys.

Comment: The default user name is the first part of the email address that you authenticate to Google Cloud with. The SSH keys are stored in `~/.ssh`. If you have used more than one credential, then you will have multiple login IDs. Google does not have the user `root` enabled for login, so double-check your configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you SSH into the Compute Engine, SSH keys are created for you.  This also created a Linux account.  The configuration of this account (eg. what groups a new account should be a member of) is defined in the file called `/etc/default/instance_configs.cfg`.  If you edit that file you will find an entry that reads:

```
[Accounts]
...
groups = adm,dip,docker,lxd,plugdev,video
...
```

This is the list of groups that the user is added when the account is created.  You were specifically asking about adding the user to the `docker` group and you may be surprised to see that `docker` is already in the list as a default.  You may then be wondering "Why is my user not a member of the docker group?".

I'm guessing that you have created a Compute Engine and then logged in and then installed the docker package.  Pause here.  The first time you logged in, that was when the account was created and THAT was when the user would have been added to groups.  However, at that initial login, docker had not been installed and hence docker group had not yet been created and hence the user could not be added to a non-existent group.

As a test, try the following.

From Cloud Shell, run:

```
gcloud compute ssh bob@[YOUR_INSTANCE] --zone=[ZONE]
```

This will create a new identity (bob) and login you in as `bob`.  Run the the `id` command and now let us see what groups you are a member of.

Comment: Ah wow...this is really interesting. yes, you are right on the money!